# This malloc shouldn't work

Tags: c, malloc

Here is my code.

```
 int     main()
  {
  char *s;
  int i = 0;

  printf("%lu \n", sizeof(s));

  s = malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);

  printf("%lu \n", sizeof(s));
  /*Why is this working?*/
  while (i <= 5)
    {
      s[i] = 'l';
      i++;
    }
  printf("%s \n", s);

  printf("%lu \n", sizeof(char));

  printf("%lu \n", sizeof(s[0]));
  }
```

In my opinion, this should segfault as I'm trying to write more than I allocated. Why is this working?

Comment: Appearing to succeed is a valid form of undefined behaviour

Comment: Probably just luck ...

Comment: Undefined behavior is different from a `segfault`. Google "what is a segfault" and Google will happily tell you that your use case here is not the same as "accessing memory the CPU cannot physically address"

Comment: Why do you expect it will give you an error? In most cases it will run just fine (as in yours). It depends **where** are you writing.

Comment: side note: use `%zu` when printing integers of type `size_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***In illustration*** *(and complete agreement with) @Ed S's answer*, Try this example of your code with the small additions of an additional variable declared exactly the same way and malloc'ed right after the `char *s`.

***Although no guarantees*** that the variables are stored sequentially in memory, creating them this way makes it a high probability.  *If so*, `char *t` will now own the space that `char *s` will encroach on, and you *will* get a seg fault:

```
int     main()
{
    char *s;
    char *t;//addition
    int i = 0;

    printf("%lu \n", sizeof(s));

    s = malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);
    t = malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);//addition

    printf("%lu \n", sizeof(s));
    /*Why is this working?*/
    while (i <= 5)
    {
      s[i] = 'l';
      i++;
    }
    printf("%s \n", s);

    printf("%lu \n", sizeof(char));

    printf("%lu \n", sizeof(s[0]));
}
```

***Note:***  In the environment I use, (Windows 7, NI Run-Time, debug, etc) I get a seg-fault either way, which somewhat supports the undefined behavior assertions in other answers.

Answer (score 6):

> In my opinion, this should segfault as I'm trying to write more than I allocated. Why is this working?

It's not "working"; your code invokes undefined behavior.  "Undefined behavior" doesn't mean "your code will segfault."  That would be *defined* behavior.  UB means anything can happen.

In this case, you're stomping on memory you don't own. That will sometimes segfault, but don't count on it.  C has no notion of "segfaults", that comes from your OS.

Comment: Clearly stated.  Nice.

Answer (score 3):

Segfault is a *signal* from the OS telling you that accessing a particular memory zone is none of your business. It just so happens that what you're accessing doesn't trigger alarms from the OS's memory management unit. There are tons of ways to exploit that (overriding function calls, attacks on binaries by overwriting stack values etc).

It may also be the case that your malloc doesn't allocate those 2 bytes and 2 bytes only. Malloc invokes a system call that allocates *virtual memory pages* (which are likely way more than 2 bytes). That syscall (`sbrk` and `VirtualAlloc` for Linux and Windows, respectively) tells the OS to map those pages onto what you need, then protect them so that nobody else (read: another process/application) accidentally treads on your memory zone ('cause in that case the OS would hit *that* one's head with a segfault).

And there's also the undefined behavior thing the others mentioned.

Comment: It's a good explanation, but technically, it's not `malloc` who protects memory pages from other processes - this is the operating system's job. The way you wrote it makes it sound like it's `malloc` who does this.

Answer (score 1):

it's seems like this: malloc allocates some bytes more than you specify..

when you use  malloc(sizeof(s)*2);  //8
then while (i <= 36) is ok, but while (i <= 37) already not..

when you use e.g malloc(sizeof(s)*4);  //16
then while (i <= 7572) is ok, but while (i <= 7573) already not..

(I tested in code::blocks)

Too bad that Dennis Ritchie is dead, it's still big mystery why it's like
that, but just don' worry about it too much just allocate always enough
you need and null terminate strings too

Comment: The behavior you are speaking of has nothing to do with C (or Dennis Ritchie).  The _mystery_ as you called it is really not a mystery at all, it is simply ***[undefined behavior](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UndefinedBehavior)***.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, its hit or miss whether the code will cause a runtime error in production since bounds checking is not built into C++ (unlike languages Java or C#). The code will cause an error under a memory checker.

You probably know Valgrind, so that's an exercise left to the reader. Here's the same under Clang's [Address Sanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) (I added a `printf("malloc: %p \n", s);`):

```
$ ./t.exe | /usr/local/bin/asan_symbolize.py 
malloc: 0x60200000b3b0 
=================================================================
==98557==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60200000b3b2 at pc 0x1065c4b5b bp 0x7fff5963b810 sp 0x7fff5963b808
WRITE of size 1 at 0x60200000b3b2 thread T0
    #0 0x1065c4b5a (/Users/jwalton/./t.exe+0x100000b5a)
    #1 0x7fff870e27e0 (/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib+0x27e0)
    #2 0x0
0x60200000b3b2 is located 0 bytes to the right of 2-byte region [0x60200000b3b0,0x60200000b3b2)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x1065d8cd5 (/usr/local/lib/clang/3.3/lib/darwin//libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib+0xfcd5)
    #1 0x1065c4971 (/Users/jwalton/./t.exe+0x100000971)
    #2 0x7fff870e27e0 (/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib+0x27e0)
    #3 0x0
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x1c0400001620: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x1c0400001630: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x1c0400001640: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x1c0400001650: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x1c0400001660: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
=>0x1c0400001670: fa fa fa fa fa fa[02]fa fa fa 00 00 fa fa fd fa
  0x1c0400001680: fa fa fd fa fa fa 00 00 fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa
  0x1c0400001690: fa fa 00 00 fa fa 00 00 fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa
  0x1c04000016a0: fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa
  0x1c04000016b0: fa fa 00 00 fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa 00 00
  0x1c04000016c0: fa fa 00 00 fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa 00 00
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:     fa
  Heap right redzone:    fb
  Freed heap region:     fd
  Stack left redzone:    f1
  Stack mid redzone:     f2
  Stack right redzone:   f3
  Stack partial redzone: f4
  Stack after return:    f5
  Stack use after scope: f8
  Global redzone:        f9
  Global init order:     f6
  Poisoned by user:      f7
  ASan internal:         fe
==98557==ABORTING
```